# Limits that take on a range rather than a unique value

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I've come across two limits which are reported to take on a range of values rather than a unique one.

They are:

$$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \space\frac{1+\cos x}{1-\sin x} = 0 \space to\space \infty$$

$$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \space \frac{2+2x+\sin(2x)}{(2x+\sin(2x))e^{\sin x}} =  \frac{1}{e} \space to \space e$$

These answers seem to contradict what I know and understand as the definition of a limit. I'm self-studying maths so am clearly missing something here.

My questions:

1. How are these limits solved?
2. Why do they exist? Why is a range of values allowed here?
3. What kind of books should I read to learn more about this? If you could provide references that would be perfect.

ETA results from Wolfram:

[The First](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20x-%3Einf%20((1%2Bcosx)%2F(1-sinx)))
[The Second](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20x-%3Einf%20((2%2B2x%2Bsin2x)%2F(2x%2Bsin2x)e%5E(sinx)))

Comment: These functions are oscillatory and dont approach a value. Limit doesn't exist in such cases

Comment: OK, that’s what I thought too. But why does Wolfram report a result for the limit, and not that the limit does not exist?

Comment: Related are the concepts of lim sup and lim inf; you might check those out in an analysis text.

Comment: [Relevant documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FindingLimits.html)

Comment: For what it's worth, the term [cluster set](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cluster+set%22+function+limit) is often used for the set of all "limiting values" (and not just the least and greatest "limiting values" --- these are the liminf and limsup) of a function at a point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the usual sense (and common definition), these limits **do not** exist (since, loosely speaking, the function values don't come arbitrarily close to a specific value for sufficiently large values of $x$).

For a simpler example, consider:
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \sin x$$
The fact that $\sin x$ keeps taking (all) values in the interval $[-1,1]$, even for arbitrary large values of $x$, can be used as an argument *against* the existence of this limit.

Of course, saying that $\sin x$ keeps taking values in $[-1,1]$ contains *more information* than simply saying "the limit does not exist", so it can be useful to consider (and determine) this range - although I would never say "the limit is [a range]".

Answer (score 1):

The limits **definitely do not** exist for these expressions. Don't let any resources on the web convince you otherwise. However, that said, the [limits inferior and superior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior) may exist. So, a more accurate rendition of your first "limit" is:
$$
\liminf_{x\to\infty}\frac{1+\cos(x)}{1-\sin(x)} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\inf_{t \ge x}\frac{1+\cos(t)}{1-\sin(t)} = 0 \text{ (as } \cos(t)=-1 \text{ infinitely often above any } x \text{)}
$$
and
$$
\limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac{1+\cos(x)}{1-\sin(x)} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\sup_{t \ge x}\frac{1+\cos(t)}{1-\sin(t)} = \infty \text{ (as } \sin(t)=1 \text{ infinitely often above any } x \text{)}
$$

This is why the resources across the web claim that the "limit exists as a range of values between zero and infinity"

Comment: To avoid confusion, I wouldn't say sequences here (note that you also mix $n$ and $x$).

Comment: Ah yes, thank you for pointing out the typo

Answer (score 0):

Take first limit for example it means that you can find an increasing sequence (because $x$ goes to $\infty$, in general the sequence doesn't need to be increasing it should just converge to the what $x$ is tending to). $x_n$ for any value of $L\in[0,\infty]$ so that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1+\cos x_n}{1-\sin x_n}=L$$
The limit doesn't exist but in certain scenarios it's good to know what are the possible values in case you're looking for a particular sequence of $x$'s, for example $$\lim_{x\to \infty}x-\lfloor x\rfloor$$
Can be anything from $0$ to $1$ but if you're interested only in integers then the limit converges to $0$.